# Get Post Id from Url using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have this Url: http://herbalista.co/1r previously posted on my timeline with the Id = 1635826883323920
How to get that Id with FQL?
I have tryied this
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+id+FROM+object_url+WHERE+url=%27http://herbalista.co/1r%27

and its return a different id = 1128761283806609

the post Id runs ok to embed a post but the returned Id doesn't works...
I'm using:

```
$posturl = "https://www.facebook.com/herbalistas/posts/".$id;

<div class="fb-post" data-href="$posturl" data-width="400"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="$shortened"><p></p></blockquote></div></div>
```

I think that the returned Id is global for the link but not the original Id from the original post on my timeline

Comment: You know that FQL is deprecated and will stop working completely in around a year

Comment: oh yes i know that but i have to use it while there it's not alternative...or there is?? what do you suggest???

Comment: That doesn't look like a post ID, it's too short - are you taking part of the URL and assuming that's the post ID? that won't work - you should be making an API (or FQL) call to fetch all posts on your profile and looking for it there

Comment: I find the solution:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+link_id+FROM+link+WHERE+owner=[USER_ID]+AND+url=%27[URL]%27LIMIT%201000&access_token=[FULL-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN]

it fetch all posts on user timeline and filter it by url

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+link_id+FROM+link+WHERE+owner=[USER_ID]+AND+url=%27[URL]%27LIMIT%201000&access_token=[FULL-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN]

it fetch all posts on user timeline and filter it by url